# El searchview me anula la vista(View) de busqueda por filtro, ¿Como cancelar el searchView?

Tags: android, menú, searchview

No sabia como formular la pregunta pero intentare ser mas explicito en el desarrollo; Tengo un searchView el cual busco en un recycleview mercaderia. hasta ahi todo ok.

Codigo searchView

```
//CREAMOS MENU PARA BUSCAR ARTICULOS - Declaracion V7.SEARCHVIEW
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchfile, menu);
    final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();


    changeSearchViewTextColor(searchView);
    ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).
            setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.icons));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
                searchView.setIconified(true);
            }
            myActionMenuItem.collapseActionView();

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            final List<ArticulosBean> filtermodelist = filter(list, newText);
            pAdapter.setfilter(filtermodelist);
            return true;
        }

    });

    return true;
}
```

Luego el metodo para almacenar la nueva lista:

```
  //CREAMOS METODO DE TIPO LIST PARA RECIBIR LOS NUEVOS ARTICULOS SEGUN ESCRITURA
private List<ArticulosBean> filter(List<ArticulosBean> pl, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    final List<ArticulosBean> filteredModeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ArticulosBean model : pl) {
        final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query.toString())) {
            filteredModeList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModeList;
}
```

Bien hasta aca todo bien. con esto me permito hacer las busquedas sobre la lista. 
El problema viene cuando agrego un item al menu para filtrar por rubro (ej. Permfumeria, Bazar, Bebidas, etc).

```
    //METODO PARA LLENAR LA LISTA CON LOS ARTICULOS SEGUN RUBRO
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.overflow: //NUEVO ITEM OVERFLOW

            final String[] arrays = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rubros_item); //ARRRAY PREDEFINIDO

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScrollingActivity.this); //MUESTRO EL ARRAY EN UN ALERT DIALOG

            builder.setTitle("Elige un rubro:").setSingleChoiceItems(arrays, UNSELECTED, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //UNSELECT = -1
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    selected = which;
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (selected != UNSELECTED) {
                        list.clear(); //LIMPIO LISTA
                        listaArticuloPorRubro(arrays[selected].toString()); //LLENO SEGUN RUBRO
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arrays[selected], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog mDialog = builder.create();
            mDialog.show();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Si yo busco sobre el search view antes mencionado, luego este item no me responde, es decir que si quiero moverme a otra lista segun rubro no me actualiza la vista, es como que el searchview me lo bloquea al metodo:

este es el metodo que me trae la nueva lista segun rubro:

```
 private void listaArticuloPorRubro(String rubro) {

    final String URLf = "https://www.servicioswebtsas.com/WebServicePedidos/lista_articulos_filtrado.php?rubro=" + rubro;
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLf, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    ArticulosBean articulos = new ArticulosBean(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_articulo"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagen_url"), //PUEDO PONER UN STRING GRACIAS A LA LIBRERIA PICASSO EN ADAPTER
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("precio"), jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("stock"));

                    list.add(articulos);

                }
                pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("PENDRIVE", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("ERROR LISTA", error.toString());
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

espero haber sido claro!, muchas gracias por su paciencia de leer mi problemática.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chicos encontre la solucion:
me esta olvidando de cargar la lista en caso de que el searchview tenga un text vacio. y esto va de la siguiente manera:

```
private void listaArticuloPorRubro(String rubro) {

    final String URLf = "https://www.servicioswebtsas.com/WebServicePedidos/lista_articulos_filtrado.php?rubro=" + rubro;
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLf, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    ArticulosBean articulos = new ArticulosBean(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre_articulo"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("imagen_url"), //PUEDO PONER UN STRING GRACIAS A LA LIBRERIA PICASSO EN ADAPTER
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("precio"),
                            jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("stock"));

                    list.add(articulos);

                }
                //CORRIJO ERROR QUE AL MOMENTO DE BUSCAR UN PRODUCTO ME ROMPIA EL ITEM SELECTED DEL OVERFLOW
                final List<ArticulosBean> filtermodelist = filter(list, "");
                pAdapter.setfilter(filtermodelist);

                pAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("PENDRIVE", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("ERROR LISTA", error.toString());
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}
```

final List filtermodelist = filter(list, "");
                    pAdapter.setfilter(filtermodelist);
eso me faltaba!!!! 
Muchas gracias!